# Angular directive with bootstrap-table

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, bootstrap-table

I'm building a directive that transforms a normal table into a bootstrap-table. The problem is that when I initialize the plugin inside the directive's link function it doesn't work well.

If I run:

```
$("myTable").bootstrapTable({
        classes: 'table-no-bordered',
        fixedColumns: true,
        fixedNumber: 3
      });
```

from the browser inspector, it works perfect!

If I run:

```
  function tableLink($scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log("LINK TABLE", element);

    $scope.$watchGroup(['heading', 'rows'], function(newValues, oldValues) {
      console.log("WATCH", newValues, oldValues);

      $(element).bootstrapTable({
        classes: 'table-no-bordered',
        fixedColumns: true,
        fixedNumber: 3
      });

    }, true);
  }
```

This is how I fill my table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="col in heading">{{col}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
        <td class="text-muted" ng-repeat="field in row track by $index">{{field}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Inside my directive's link functions, then my table shows the message `No matching records found` at the bottom, and no other configuration seems to work.

I've already tried moving the initialization code outside the `$scope.$watch`
I'm filling the table with data from a webservice.

Do you guys have any idea what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Show how you fill table. If it uses `ng-repeat` you need to defer to another digest to give `ng-repeat` time to render ( try $timeout). I suggest you use one of the many available angular table/grid modules, many of which are css framework agnostic

Comment: I do use ng-repeat to fill my table. I've already tried placing the jquery plugin's initialization inside $timeout and don't see any diference

Comment: this could be made to work but i suggest you look for an alternate that has already been angularized and battle tested...lots of choices out there

Comment: What would you suggest to make this work?

Comment: i use [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#top) quite a bit

Comment: Ok @charlietfl I found out that if I initialize the table outside of the link function (But inside the directive), it works. But if I try to initialize it inside my directive's link function it doesn't. Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: not really...and i wouldn't trust that too much myself